# Can I install sql server on Win XP machine with user profile on D drive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows, sql-server-express

Is it possible to install sql server on a windows xp machine where the user profiles are created on a non system root directory, that is, on D drive rather than C drive?

I am trying to install SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: Why are you asking? Did you try it and it failed?

Comment: Yes, it is failing. I am not sure if this could be the reason for the installation to fail.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message, error codes, etc.

Comment: The error code is 15209, error during encryption. But, I want to know will Sql server installation fail if the Network service account is on D drive instead of C drive.

Comment: It shouldn't fail. Based on the error message, the failure is probably due to something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft support document might be of some help in regards to that particular error: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2387754

> The Network Service account does not have permissions on the following folder:
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Application Data\Microsoft\Protect

It might need permission to that particular directory on your D Drive